# Editar o texto de uma div e de seus filhos ao clicar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como editar o texto de uma `div` ou de seus filhos ao clicar no texto, com **JavaScript** ou **jQuery**?

Exemplo, ao clicar duas vezes em **Texto aqui** ser possível alterar o texto e/ou apaga-lo

```css
#alterar {background:#e3e3e3;padding:15px;}
#naoAlterar {background:#ccc;padding:5px;margin:-5px}
```

```html
<div id="alterar">
Texto aqui
<p>Texto aqui</p>
<span>Texto aqui</span>
<br/><br/>
<div id="naoAlterar">Texto aqui</div>
</div>
```

Comment: O evento dblclick é enviado para um elemento quando o elemento é clicado duas vezes. Qualquer elemento HTML pode receber este evento. https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar à div `contentEditable="true"`para tornar o elemento editável: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

Como você quer isso apenas do duplo click, pode fazer isso usando um evento:

```js
$('#banner-message').dblclick(function() {
   $(this).attr("contentEditable","true");
});

$('#banner-message').blur(function() {
   $(this).attr("contentEditable","false");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message" >
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```